# missing type specifier - int assumed Error after declaration of static member

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, sdl-2

I get the following error message after compiling my code:

> Error C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
>   support default-int on    line    21

I dont really know why the AssetManager retrieves that error, since I included everything needed...
My code:

game.hpp

```
#pragma once
#include "SDL.h"
#include "SDL_image.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "AssetManager.hpp"

class Game {
public:
    Game();
    ~Game();

    void init(const char* title, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height, bool fullscreen);

    void handleEvents();
    void update();
    bool running() { return isRunning; };
    void render();
    void clean();

    static AssetManager* assets;
////////
}
```

AssetManager.hpp

```
#pragma once
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include "TextureManager.hpp"
#include "Vector2D.hpp"
#include "ECS.hpp"

class AssetManager {
public:
    AssetManager(Manager* man);
    ~AssetManager();

    void AddTexture(std::string id, const char* path);
    SDL_Texture* GetTexture(std::string id);

private:
    Manager* manager;
    std::map<std::string, SDL_Texture*> textures;
};
```

Comment: So which line has the error ?

Comment: static AssetManager* assets;

Comment: In your `game.hpp` file you have the function `bool running() { return isRunning; };`
But the variable `isRunning` does not seem to exist.

Comment: I didnt include the whole code in the Class Game. The program fully works right up to the point where i implemented the AssetManager...

Comment: My guess would be, `AssetManager.hpp` indirectly includes `game.hpp`, so now you have a circular include.

Comment: My god, that was it! thank you. Didn't even see it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a problem of circular dependency. Try forward declaration for AssetManager something like this:-
Class AssetManager; instead of #include "AssetManager.hpp"  in game.hpp